# Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger, stops Wamp Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, wamp

Please can someone help me, am getting this message whenever I start my windows 7 system:

Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger.
An unhandled exception ('System.IO.FileNotFoundException') occured in IAStorDataMgrSvc.exe [5824]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

I have uninstalled Visual Studio yet this challenge persists.

Because of the above error I can no longer properly use my wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install IIS when you installed Visual Studio.

IIS and the APache in WAMP are both web servers and both want to use TCP port 80. IIS is probably staring automatically and getting port 80 first so Apache cannot have it.
If you are not using IIS then uninstall it as well.

If you are then you will have to change IIS and probably some other bits so they dont start automaticaly. Do this on the Services dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got the same problem.
I dont know about the relationship betwin Visual studio and Wamp, and I somehow doubt its related, sence at the instal of VS2017 Ive had already instaled Wamp.
What I do know is that, even in offline instal mode this problem persists, my gues is that JustINtimeDebugger got locked.

## My solution:

I killed the PowerShell.exe process (under vs_instalershell ) using [File Explorer](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip) and install it later.

## Note, this does not solve the problem it just bypass it.

Theoreticaly, next you should try to unlock the `RegisterJustInTimeDebugger.ps1` file from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0` with (consider changing the path if needed):
`Unblock-File -path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0"`

## Altenative:

Update the System Variable __PSLockDownPolicy to 1 or delete it if it exists.

But I have failed to make it working even now.